# Iterating through database resultset in Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I just hoped you could help me understand this:

In the below, does chunk size submit lots of queries to the database? Or does it one run query & just process the chunks one by one?

I have a super slow database with lots of data. So, ideally, I want to query once, but handle it in chunks to avoid memory overload on the EC2 instance

Thanks

```
for data in pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM TABLE ', iconn,  chunksize=10000000)
```

Comment: chunksize parameter is transferred to _query_iterator and from there to fetchmany. I'm not sure if fetchmany uses the parameter as a limit to query, but I guess you can check the database if there are queries like yours with a limit